# Why is there no main() in bitcoin source?

Tags: c++, bitcoin

I am working my way through the [bitcoin source code](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src) but I can't seem to find the

```
int main(){

}
```

part.

The only main() I can find appears to be a QT test in [qt/bitcoin.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/qt/bitcoin.cpp)

Is there something I am overlooking, with respect to how the program would 'start'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found `int main(...)` right here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.9.3/src/bitcoind.cpp#L173-L188